# Javascript XSLT Transformation with XML stored in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xslt

I need to transform an XML string using XSLT in Javascript. While the XSLT is stored in its own file, the XML is part of a bigger XML document, and therefor stored as a string in a variable.

My current solution looks as follows:

```
xslt = document.implementation.createDocument("","",null);
xslt.async = false;
xslt.load('xslfile.xsl');

xml = document.implementation.createDocument("","",null);
// here I need to include the XML as it is in the document

xsltProc.importStylesheet(xslt);
xml_dom = xsltProc.transformToDocument(xml);
output += new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xml_dom.documentElement);
```

When I save the content of the variable to a file and include it the way I included the XSLT file, I get the desired output (the transformed XML):

```
xml = document.implementation.createDocument("","",null);
xml.async = false;
xml.load('xmlinput.xml');
```

I need a way to include the content of the variable to the xml DOM document...or is there a more elegant way?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Mozilla, Opera, Safari, Chrome and with IE 9 you can do e.g.

```
var xml = new DOMParser().parseFromString(yourVar, 'application/xml');
```

to parse the XML markup in the variable `yourVar` into an XML DOM document.

Answer (score 0):

You can store XML in a variable and use jQuery as normal to traverse it, i tend to do something like this:

```
window.auditDoc = $.parseXML("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Bundle><Audit></Audit></Bundle>");
```

If i'm doing allot of work with a single xml file then i also find it useful to put it up in window.auditDoc and always refer to it as that.